# How do I insert a value in a custom field in a table in Prestashop?

Tags: mysql, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I added a custom field named "deldate" in "ps_orders" table, and I added a text box on "OPC" checkout page. Now when I click on order confirm button the value in the textbox should be saved in "deldate" field of "ps_orders" table. 
The textbox is showing perfectly but in which files do I need to make changes to save the textbox value in the table?
(Theme is default one.)

[image: snap of textbox]

[image: snap of custom field in table.]

class/order/order.php

```
class OrderCore extends ObjectModel 
{ 
public $deldate; 
}
```

And

```
public static $definition = array( 
'fields' => array( 
'deldate'=> array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),
),
)
```

Shopping-cart.tpl

```
<div class="box">
<div class="required form-group">
<form method="post">
<label for="Fecha de entrega deseada">{l s='Desired delivery date' mod='deldate'}</label>
<input type="text" id="deldate" name="deldate" class="form-control" value="hello" />
</form>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: My friend, you have missed all the 'model' and 'controller' code :), you have to edit the controller, I guess `ParentOrderController` and the model `Order`

Comment: hello, I made changes in class/order/order.php  but later i am getting an error of bankwire/validation during order confirmation.

Comment: Post your edits, so we can help you better

Comment: ok i added
`class OrderCore extends ObjectModel
{

    public $deldate;

}`

And

`public static $definition = array(
'fields' => array( 'deldate'=>      array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING),),
)`

Comment: That's not how you extend core objects... you need to extend from OrderCore.

Comment: So same i did in class/order/order.php  in OrderCore class as you can see above comment.

Comment: Please, post in the question not as a comment ;)

Comment: ohk done, Now you can see

Comment: Well then you need to modify `validateOrder` method of `PaymentModule` class. But really a better way is to create a module and use hooks. Modifying core files is a bad idea since you will lose modifications when updating prestashop.

Comment: if i use override?

Comment: what i need to exactly add in `validateOrder` method of `PaymentModule` class

Comment: sidenote: i would recommend not using `string` but `datetime` and the appropriate validations. Pretty sure you don't want customers to write stuff like "next thursday" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the solution...
If you want to add some information to the order in the checkout process you have to save this informations elsewhere, if you look the cart table are very similar to order table.
Why you have to do this? Because you don't have an order  before the confirmation by customer, so until the checkout is not complete that informations can't be saved in the order table.

So, first, create the field in database, in this case you have to add in `ps_orders` and in the `ps_cart` as well.
(In your case I suggest to use a DATETIME field)

Second, override the Order class:

```
class Order extends OrderCore
{
    public function __construct($id = null, $id_lang = null)
    {
        self::$definition['fields']['deldate'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE);

        parent::__construct($id, $id_lang);
    }
}
```

and the `Cart` class:

```
class Cart extends CartCore
{
    public function __construct($id = null, $id_lang = null)
    {
        self::$definition['fields']['deldate'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE);

        parent::__construct($id, $id_lang);
    }
}
```

Now we have to save the field during the checkout process, so we override the `OrderController`:

```
class OrderController extends OrderControllerCore
{
    public function processAddress()
    {
        parent::processAddress();

        // Here we begin our story
        if(Tools::getIsset('deldate')) // Check if the field isn't empty
        {
            $deldate = Tools::getValue('deldate');

            // Here you must parse and check data validity (I leave to you the code)
            /* ... */

            // Assign the data to context cart
            $this->context->cart->deldate = $deldate;
            // Save information
            $this->context->cart->update();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have to 'transport' this informations from the cart to the order, this will be done through the `PaymentModule` class, specifically with the `validateOrder` method.

So, another override:

```
class PaymentModule extends PaymentModuleCore
{
    public function validateOrder($id_cart, $id_order_state, $amount_paid, $payment_method = 'Unknown', $message = null, $extra_vars = array(), $currency_special = null, $dont_touch_amount = false, $secure_key = false, Shop $shop = null)
    {
        $result = parent::validateOrder($id_cart, $id_order_state, $amount_paid, $payment_method, $message, $extra_vars, $currency_special, $dont_touch_amount, $secure_key, $shop);

        if($result)
        {
            $oldcart = new Cart($id_cart);
            $neworder = new Order($this->currentOrder);
            $neworder->deldate = $oldcart->deldate;
            $neworder->update();
            return true; // important
        } 
        else 
        {
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

After all of this you have the `deldate` field saved. However, I absolutely don't suggest this method, it's more safe and simple with a module and hooks... But this is another story :)

This will works only with the five steps checkout.

For next code lines, God save me...

If you want to works with OPC you have to dirty your hands with JS and override the `OrderOpcController`.
Start with the JS, edit the `order-opc.js` in js folder of enabled theme, find `bindInputs` function and append this lines of code:

```
function bindInputs()
{
    /* ... */

    $('#deldate').on('change', function(e){
        updateDelDateInput(); // custom function to update deldate
    });
}
```

then append to the file your custom function:

```
function updateDelDateInput()
{
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
            url: orderOpcUrl + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            dataType : "json",
            data: 'ajax=true&method=updateDelDate&deldate=' + encodeURIComponent($('#deldate').val()) + '&token=' + static_token ,
            success: function(jsonData)
            {
                if (jsonData.hasError)
                {
                    var errors = '';
                    for(var error in jsonData.errors)
                        //IE6 bug fix
                        if(error !== 'indexOf')
                            errors += $('<div />').html(jsonData.errors[error]).text() + "\n";
                    alert(errors);
                }
                // Here you can add code to display the correct updating of field
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (textStatus !== 'abort')
                    alert("TECHNICAL ERROR: unable to save message \n\nDetails:\nError thrown: " + XMLHttpRequest + "\n" + 'Text status: ' + textStatus);
            }
        });
}
```

Then override the `OrderOpcController`, copy all the `init` method and change the line of code as below:

```
class OrderOpcController extends OrderOpcControllerCore
{
    public function init()
    {
        // parent::init(); // comment or delete this line
        FrontController::init(); // Very important!
        // Then in this switch `switch (Tools::getValue('method'))` add your case
        /* ... */
        case 'updateDelDate':
            if(Tools::isSubmit('deldate'))
            {
                $deldate = urldecode(Tools::getValue('deldate'));

                // Here you must parse and check data validity (I leave to you the code)
                /* ... */

                // Assign the data to context cart
                $this->context->cart->deldate = $deldate;
                // Save information
                $this->context->cart->update();
                $this->ajaxDie(true);
            }
        break;
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Obviously, is necessary the override of `Order`, `Cart` and `PaymentModule` as well.

PS: I hope that I didn't forget anything.

Comment: thanks I am trying this method but i am showing textbox using a custom module right now inside the form tag so should i remove that form tag.

Comment: I am using OPC Checkout here. And I placed textbox code in Shopping-cart.tpl  I have done as you said but no value saved yet. I added shopping-cart.tpl code also in post.

Comment: As I wrote, this method works only with five steps checkout, there is other code to write for the OPC :)

Comment: ohk can you give me just hint and what changes only. Please bro :)
I think we need to make changes in PaymentModule, OrderController.

Comment: hello are you there?

Comment: @techdishoom I hope that I answer to your question now :)

Comment: :p but let me know about changes need to do for OPC checkout.

Comment: My friend I added in the answer yesterday :)

Comment: Will it work with the webservice when an order is created using it?

Comment: @Dhara In theory it should work, if not, there is another definition var to tell to PrestaShop the new field available for the WS

Answer (score 1):

You can try also with this module
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/589259-m%C3%B3dulo-selector-fecha-en-pedido/?p=2489523

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the override of the class Order

```
class Order extends OrderCore
{

    public function __construct($id = null, $id_lang = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($id, $id_lang);

        self::$definition['fields']['deldate'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING);
        Cache::clean('objectmodel_def_Order');

    }

}
```

The Cache::clean is need because getDefinition tries to retrieve from cache, and cache is set without the override on parent::__construct

I then tried to create a new empty Order and get the definition fields and it showed there, so it should save to mysql

```
$order = new Order();
var_dump(ObjectModel::getDefinition($order));exit;
```